# Receiving XML from POST query

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, xml, routes

I'm interfacing an application with Rails.

In some queries, I get a POST request with standard URL parameters, and a body containing XML (generated with stdin JAVA method from client).

My route is simple :

```
post '/server/r' => 'my_controller#r', :as => :my_controller_r
```

The server have theses logs :

```
Started POST "/server/r?c=2" for X.X.X.X at 2015-01-30 12:50:51 +0100
Processing by MyController#r as HTML
  Parameters: {"<?xml version"=>"\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><cache><file md5=\"fc27e691ccb48681e38b8e343915af14\"/><file md5=\"ceda00890578762c6fac96f1a43f671a\"/></cache>", "c"=>"2"}
```

I see the correct parameters `c => '2'`, but all the body is interpreted as an hash, with a key `"<?xml version"`.

I can make it work using `Hash.from_xml("<?xml version=#{params["<?xml version"]}")` but it's dirty.

Is that a bad configuration of my routes, or a bad request from client ?

Regards

Comment: How you are sending request?

Comment: @Sanjiv I don't send any request, I receive it from a JAVA client (not mine)

Comment: So you does not have control over data sources?

Comment: @Sanjiv no... I just know that's body is created with standard JAVA methods stdin.